# Angle to bypass circle at n distance and direction

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, angle, tangent-line

Forgive me if this is rather basic (I never did trig!). I'd like to work out the red angle in the picture below, assuming the black dot is ***n*** distance from the circle. It could also be in a different position (offset left or right from the center of the circle).

[image]

For example, lets say the circle is 10 metres in diameter, the dot is at a distance of 2 metres from the edge of the circle. How can we calculate the most efficient angle between the x and y axis that would allow a line (e.g. the one in purple) to be drawn from the dot, past the circle?

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sure, I don't want to contribute bad posts here. I think however my question is straight forward and easy to understand. What would you change?

Comment: For instance, I do not understand the meaning of the expression “the black dot is $n$ distance from the circle”. Would you please edit it?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Done, hope that helps to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as stated, can't be solved. In fact, if you rotate the circle around the black dot, the value of $n$ remains the same, but the angles will be different.

I will solve the problem assuming that the coordinates of $n$ are both equal to $0$ and that the circle (I shall call it $c$) is centered at $(a,b)$ with radius $r$. I shall also assume that the circle lies in the upper half-plane (that is, $b>0$ and $r<b$). In that case, the tangency points must have these properties:

- they belong to the circle;
- the lini joining $(0,0)$ to the tangency point is orthogonal to the line joining the tangency point to the center of the circle (that is, to $(a,b)$).

This means that we have to solve the system of equations$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2\\(x,y).(x-a),y-b)=0.\end{array}\right.$$It has two solutions $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, which are$$\begin{cases}\left(\dfrac{a^3+a(b^2-r^2)\pm\frac{|a|}abr\sqrt{a^2+b^2-r^2}}{a^2+b^2},\dfrac{a^2b+b^3-br^2\mp|a|r\sqrt{a^2+b^2-r^2}}{a^2+b^2}\right)&\text{ if }a\neq0\\\left(\pm r\sqrt{1-\dfrac{r^2}{b^2}},b-\dfrac{r^2}b\right)&\text{ if }a=0.\end{cases}$$The angles that you are interested in are $\arctan\left(\frac{y_1}{x_1}\right)$ and $\arctan\left(\frac{y_2}{x_2}\right)$.